# Print all pairs of values in column of tsv file via bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, awk

I want to write a small shell script to make a labeling task easier for myself. Alas, I'm still lacking the skills to do so.

I've got a news.tsv file which looks like this:

```
id  foo  bar text 
1   a    b   lorem
2   c    d   ipsum
...
50  e    f   muspi
```

Where the actual entries in the text column are lengthy news articles. I want to print 2 of these texts at once, until all possible pairs in the column have been printed.

Searching for a solution, I found that awk might be the right tool for the task. I know how to print two specific entries in the text column, e.g,

```
awk -F '\t' 'NR==2 {print $4} NR==3 {print $4}' news.tsv
```

will print lorem and ipsum. For getting all pairs, I think I'll need a nested for-loop, but I fail at implementing it with awk.

My spaghetti-try looks like this:

```
awk -F '\t' '{for (i=0; i<50; i++){for (j=i+1; j<50; j++) if(i!=j){NR==i {print $4} NR==j {print $4}}}}' news.tsv
```

I'm open for other tools as well.

Comment: Does your 'spaghetti code' do what you want?

Comment: Can `text` contain `tabs`? You say lengthy articles -- what guarantee do you have there is no other tab in text?

Comment: `2 of these texts at once, until all possible pairs in the column have been printed`  what does that mean? Can you post example output you expect to get?

Comment: Can you desired output ?

Comment: Does the order of the output pairs matter? I mean if you print `foo bar` then should you also print `bar foo` or not.

Comment: I apologize for vagueness or missing information in my question. Hope the next one will be clearer. I don't know whether answering comments is expected after the question has been answered, but I will do so:
@tink my code does not do what I want but produced some errors near the curly braces. I'll add that info to any further questions of mine, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `text`does not contain `tabs`, as I have already preprocessed the data in that way.

Comment: @dash-o I will add desired output to any questions I have in the future, thanks for pointing that out. 
ed morton: I didn't clarify it, but the order of outputs does not matter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the total amount of the texts is not so huge, it will be efficient
store the whole texts in an array. Otherwise you need to read the input file
multiple times (the number of combination).

Then how about:

```
awk -F '\t' '
    NR>1 {texts[++n]=$4}
    END {
        for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
            for (j=i+1; j<=n; j++) {
                print texts[i] " " texts[j]
            }
        }
    }' news.tsv
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $4; next; print $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt based on your own script ... assuming that there are no embedded TABs, ever.

```
$ cat awkward 
NR>1{
  a[NR-1]=$4
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=50;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=50;j++){
      if(i!=j){
        print a[i],a[j]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Invoked like so:

```
$ awk -f awkward test.tsv
Lorem ipsum
Lorem dolor
Lorem sit
Lorem amet,
Lorem consectetur
Lorem adipiscing
Lorem elit,
Lorem sed
Lorem do
Lorem eiusmod
.
.
[over 2000 lines stripped]
.
.
fugiat dolor
fugiat in
fugiat reprehenderit
fugiat in
fugiat voluptate
fugiat velit
fugiat esse
fugiat cillum
fugiat dolore
fugiat eu
```

Comment: @Gripe - your accepted answer doesn't honour `if(i!=j)` ... just putting it out there.

Comment: Hi @tink, I'm probably invoking it wrong, but for me this seems to be printing pair of words on the 7th position, instead of a pair of values from the 7th field in the tsv.

Comment: I based my script on the presented input; if that's not quite what you really have and there is whitespace in any of the fields before the fourth we can easily adjust the invocation `awk  -F'\t' -f awkward test.tsv`

Comment: @tink In my code `j` starts from `i+1` and the condition `if(i!=j)` is not required.
The number of `combination` of `N` items can be calculated by `N * (N-1) / 2`.
Your answer generates both `lorem ipsum` and `ipsum lorem` (and more...). 
I don't think this is what the OP wants.